# Installing MAYAVI in Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, fatal-error, mayavi

I installed Python 2.7 via Home brew and installed all other library packages using pip

To install Mayavi initially, I installed VTK using

```
brew reinstall --python --qt vtk5
```

Later, I did

```
pip install mayavi
```

but this gives out this error for me:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: mayavi
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mayavi ... error
Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools,                 
tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/t_/x10q3tk92ms64kcjqvxy8s8w0000gn/T/pip-
build-2zB86t/mayavi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open
(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d 
/var/folders/t_/x10q3tk92ms64kcjqvxy8s8w0000gn/T/tmpTxZtPCpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:

 running bdist_wheel
 running build
 Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
```

Could someone tell how can fix this issue or what is going wrong, apart from that my python works fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to check your environment here, via the commands

```
which python
which pip
which brew
echo $PATH
brew doctor
```

Installing Python packages on OS X where there is a compilation involved can lead to various errors related to the choice of compiler and python executable.

Answer (score 0):

I once had many problems when installing and using mayavi.

I think the best and the easiest way to use mayavi is to install [enthought canopy](https://store.enthought.com/downloads/#default)

it provides many scientific and analytic Python package distributions including mayavi, vtk and so on.

After installing it, you can visualize your data by executing the python installed in canopy (for example `/Users/zjshao/Library/Enthought/Canopy/edm/envs/User/bin/python` in my Mac). Then the mayavi would work.